# A question on creating filters for custom posts using taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization

This is my first foray into custom post types and taxonomies. I created a taxonomy-services.php page to display posts that are associated with the 'websites' slug. That seems to be working fine.

However, I want to be able to show other posts on services.php that are associated with another slug, like 'video'.

These both fall under the Services taxonomy. I'm just not sure how to filter them on the services.php page.

Can someone please help me with this challenge. I'm both PHP/WordPress noob, and need to get a quick win on this one.

Answer (score 1):

you can check on your taxonomy-services.php what is the current queried term filter based on that, something like this:

```
//get the current term
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
//get the current taxonomy
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
//get the term object if you want
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );

//then you can query your posts/custom based on that term
$s_query = NEW WP_Query(array('services' => $term_slug, 'post_type' => 'post'));

//then you can simply filter the posts
if ($current_term->term_slug == "websites"){
   while($s_query->have_posts){
      $s_query->the_post();
      //do websites loop
   }
}elseif ($current_term->term_slug == "video"){
   while($s_query->have_posts){
      $s_query->the_post();
      //do videos loop
   }
}else{
   while($s_query->have_posts){
      $s_query->the_post();
      //do any other loop of that taxonomy
   }
}
```